# Java synchronized keyword - Does it protect a class method from being executed at the same time?

Tags: java

I need some clarificaton on how the syncronized keyword works in java 6.

Using the following example class.

```
class Carrier {

   private String[] _collection = new String[2];

   public Carrier() {
       this._collection[0] = "abc";
       this._collection[1] = "123";
   }

   public syncronized void change(int cId) {
       Thread.sleep(3000);
       this._collection[cId] = "changed";
   }

}
```

Now, some place in the application, referencing the same object instance of the Carrier class, the .change() method is called, possibly at the same time.

```
...carrier.change(1);
```

...

```
...carrier.change(1);
```

Will the syncronized keyword prevent asyncronized execution of the method? Will it simply queue the call to .change(), waiting for each one to complete?

Comment: `Will it simply queue the call to .change()`. Depends on what you mean by queue. The execution order isn't specified, so it's not an ordered queue, but yes, the other threads will be forced to wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will prevent the two method calls from executing at the same time.

That is really what the main use of the `synchronized` keyword is.

When one synchronized method runs, it obtains a 'lock' on the object it is called on.  That means no other synchronized code can be run on that object while that method holds the lock.  Once the method is done executing, it will release the lock, and other synchronized methods can obtain a lock on that object.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the second thread will block while the first thread is executing. That's because they both try to acquire the monitor on the same object - via `this`, in this case. So your `change` method is equivalent to:

```
public void change(int cId) {
    synchronized (this) {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        this._collection[cId] = "changed";
    }
}
```

Personally I don't like synchronizing on "this" as it means any *other* code with access to the object itself could acquire the same monitor. I prefer to create an object *just* for locking which *only* code within the class has access to:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

public void change(int cId) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        this._collection[cId] = "changed";
    }
}
```

That will still have the same effect in terms of two threads calling `change` on the same object, because both threads will still be acquiring the same monitor - just the one associated with the lock-specific object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and yes. (Note that it's `synchronized`, not `syncronized`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the synchronized keyword prevents simultaneous execution of the method by different threads.

Note: A "class method" is a `static` method. An "instance method" (ie non-static) is what you have in your question.

Comment: Great. I'll add that to my vocabulary. Along with "being" (not beeing) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`synchronized` are used for preventing simultaneously accesses in cuncurrent programming.
For example when you have to client, one that reads and another that writes:

Lock [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) for an exhaustive explanation.